# I got the error "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1/10/24 7:00 PM"" when trying to parse

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I have a date string as "1/10/24 7:00 PM" (10th Jan.2024). How to parse it using `SimpleDateFormat`?

```
String date_time = "1/10/24 7:00 PM";
Instant answer;
try {
    answer = Instant.parse(date_time);
} catch(DateTimeParseException ex) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    answer = simpleDateFormat.parse(date_time).toInstant();
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that date isn't formatted according to the default pattern. Try and pass the correct pattern to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.

Comment: Stop using outdated classe like *SimpleDateFormat* use The DateTimeFormatter of the java.time API

Comment: You're already using the new `java.time` API (e.g. `Instant`), why do you want to revert to the older and more error prone old one based on `java.util.Date` (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`) ?

Comment: simpleDateFormat.parse(date_time , new java.text.ParsePosition(0)) you are using an extremely old and flawed "Date" API , use java.time API "since Sun/Oracle 1.8.0 (open 11)" . parse position is only a placeholder for the internal method workings.

Comment: It’s not quite as complicated as you seem to think: `Instant answer = LocalDateTime .parse(date_time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uu h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toInstant();`. <in my time zone it gave an `Instant` of `2024-01-10T18:00:00Z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a date string as "1/10/24 7:00 PM" (10th Jan.2024). How to
> parse it using SimpleDateFormat?

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

The given date-time string does not have time zone information; therefore, parse it into a `LocalDateTime` and then apply the system-default time-zone to convert it into a `ZonedDateTime`. Finally, convert the `ZonedDateTime` into an `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "1/10/24 7:00 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uu h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Instant output = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2024-01-10T19:00:00Z
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/1bJXcC)

Note that you can use [`Instant#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) only for those strings which conform to [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) e.g. `Instant.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30Z")`.

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**